# How to toggle View over UINavigationBar with animation?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have `Navigation Bar` in my App.

as shown in image below

[image]

I want on View comes from upside and cover the complete `UINavigationBar`, it can be `UIView`. and then again goes above with animation.

Comment: you want reverse of present?

Comment: just want a view (UIIMage or any other uiview) should come from above, cover whole navigation and go back from upside from where it came.

Comment: set the frame to (0,-480,320,480) and in when you want it down add it over navigation controller and change the frame to (0,0,320,480)in animation block

Comment: I don't want to hide this current navigation bar, but present new view on it.

Comment: Then add it on self.view

Answer (score 2):

You should inherit UIAlertView and show it on main View?

See code below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyAlertView : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *alertBtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *closeBtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *timer;
@property(nonatomic) int loadTime;

-(void) setAlert :(UIWindow *)currentWindow;
-(void) showAlert :(NSString *)alertText;
-(void)closeAlert;
@end



#import "MyAlertView.h"

@implementation MyAlertView
@synthesize loadTime;
@synthesize closeBtn,alertBtn,timer;
BOOL timessss=FALSE;
-(void) setAlert :(UIWindow *)currentWindow{
    loadTime=3;

    self.alertBtn=[[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.alertBtn.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;
    self.closeBtn=[[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.closeBtn.hidden=YES;
    self.alertBtn.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [[self alertBtn] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeBar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self closeBtn] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross-1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self closeBtn] addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self alertBtn] addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.alertBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.closeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(294, 17.0f, 15.0f, 15.0)];
    [self.closeBtn setHidden:YES];
    [self.alertBtn setHidden:YES];

    [currentWindow addSubview:self.alertBtn];
    //[self.alertBtn addSubview:self.closeBtn];

    //[currentWindow addSubview:self.closeBtn];

}
-(void) cancelAlert{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.alertBtn
                      duration:0.7
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations:NULL
                    completion:NULL];

    [self.alertBtn setHidden:YES];
    [self.closeBtn setHidden:YES];
    [timer invalidate];
    timessss=FALSE;

}
-(void) showAlert :(NSString *)alertText{
    if(alertBtn.isHidden);
    else return;

    [self.alertBtn setTitle:alertText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.alertBtn
                      duration:0.7
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    animations:NULL
                    completion:NULL];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.closeBtn
                      duration:0.7
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    animations:NULL
                    completion:NULL];

    [self.alertBtn setHidden:NO];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(closeAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];

}
-(void)closeAlert{
    if (timessss) {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.alertBtn
                          duration:0.7  
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                        animations:NULL
                        completion:NULL];

        [self.alertBtn setHidden:YES];
        [self.closeBtn setHidden:YES];
        [timer invalidate];
        timessss=FALSE;

    }
    else{
        timessss=TRUE;
        [self.closeBtn setHidden:NO];

    }

}
@end
```

Call it like while defining property globally,,,,

```
 //In View DidLoad
UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
alert=[[MyAlertView alloc] init];
[alert setAlert:currentWindow];

 //Wherever you want to show Alert on your navigation bar.
 [alert showAlert:@"Your Message"];
```